# Multiple entries in Add/Remove Programs of my application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, orca, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am using Visual Studio 2013 installer to package my application. I then make a copy of the MSI, open it in Orca and remove all the dialogs to create a silent package. So I have two MSI's that should be the same other than one is silent and the other is not.

When I upgrade from a previous version (built in the same way) using the non-silent package, everything works perfectly.

However when I upgrade from a previous version using the silent package, it all works apart from I am left with 2 entries in Add/Remove programs. It all works though but looks ugly for the client. When i uninstall the latest version, Add remove programs still has the previous version listed in Add/Remove programs although actually the latest version is still installed.

As I say, the non-silent package works perfectly well, which leads me to think I must have everything setup correctly in Visual Studio and Orca must be doing something I didn't intend.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two entries in Add/Remove Programs then the upgrade didn't work. A common reason is that one of the installs is Everyone and the other is Just me.  If you delete the dialogs then you have altered the behavior that sets the ALLUSERS property, and your upgrade could default to Just me. In the absence of a decision to use one of these choices VS setups use ALLUSERS=2 which is defaulting to a per user Just me install, that's the likely reason. Elevation is involved too - VS setups would rather your MSI did a successful Just me instead of a failing Everyone if privilege state is not clear (and in MSI setups it often isn't).

You might need to go to the Property table and set FolderForm_AllUsers to "ALL" and ALLUSERS to 1 to force a per machine Everyone install.

How silent do you want it to be? If it requires elevation to install successfully then you need the elevation dialog to be shown or the install will fail silently if you force a per machine Everyone install.